# ASP.NET JQuery based Modal Dialog Control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

First of all this is not a question, i just made a user control which seems to solve the issue discussed in the following link.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-will-move-its-div-tag-to-body

The issue is, briefly, JQuery dialog causes some problems when using partial page update. From ASP.NET aspect, when it is used inside an UpdatePanel.

You can see the samples and download source code from the following links.

http://www.mbmt.net/JQ/JQDialogTest.aspx
http://www.mbmt.net/JQ/JQDialogTest2.aspx

I hope this helps someone (:

Comment: While posting stuff like these isn't prohibited by the site, I'm pretty sure people would most benefit from this if you actually do take the time to phrase it like a question.

Comment: Nice work. Actually it keeps adding an additional dialog upon every postback. I came across this few months ago and used an counter to clear all the unwanted divs first and then open my dialog. I also ended up winding up my custom dialog but using same jquery UI css and injecting it from code-behind.

Comment: thank you mehmet, i think everyone should do this when they found a solution!

Comment: @Mehmet Ataş ... I don't see any download link ...

Comment: @Will: Will this question be deleted later? I would like it not to be deleted. This was helpful to at least one user (euther -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464793/gridview-inside-jquery-ui-dialog) and could potentially help others.

Comment: @gbs: It will be deleted if people vote for it to be deleted.  Really, what needs to happen is that this needs to be re-asked as a real question, and the answer be provided as a real answer.  I'm not exactly sure OP is up to the task (too new), but if he is he can prove it by asking a new question with this information, but in the correct format.